# Including a file in an included folder's parent directory fails

Tags: php, directory, relative-path, include-path

I have included a folder that contains some classes, in my `.htaccess` file.

Somewhere deeper under `public_html` I'm including a PHP file from this folder. Works fine, the `include_path` is in effect.

But if I write something like this:

```
require_once '../DB.php';
```

it fails?

This file is just above the included folder, why can't the PHP engine find it?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your server's error log?

Answer (score 2):

The relative paths are always interpreted from the current working directory (usually referred to as CWD). With web requests this is usually the file's directory that got the request to handle, but can be changed any time with [`chdir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php), you can check it's current value with [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

If you want your code to be resilient against the cwd, you can use the [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant or if you are on an ancient php version (before 5.3) the `dirname(__FILE__)` in your includes, like this:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../DB.php';
```